# Redux state returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, api, redux, react-redux

I'm a noob when it comes to using Redux and I'm running into issues retrieving data from an API and accessing it via Redux props. When I try to access data retrieved by my action it returns undefined.

Here is the component in which I am trying to use the data:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import dsteem from 'dsteem';
import { Client } from 'dsteem';
import jsonQuery from 'json-query';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUtopian } from '../actions/Utopian-action';


class Utopian extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.fetchUtopian();
    }


  render() {

   console.log(this.props.data);


    return (
      <div className="utopian-container">

      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchUtopian: () => dispatch(fetchUtopian())
})

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.utopianReducer
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Utopian);
```

Here is the action that is retrieving the data. I make an API call within the action and I think maybe it's not formatted properly. Again, I'm a Redux noob.

```
import dsteem from 'dsteem';
import { Client } from 'dsteem';

export function fetchUtopian() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_UTOPIAN" });


    const client = new Client('https://api.steemit.com')

    var utopianHot = {
      tag: 'utopian-io',
      limit: 20
    }

     client.database
       .getDiscussions('hot', utopianHot)
       .then((response) => {
         dispatch({ type: "FETCH_UTOPIAN_FULFILLED", payload: response.data })
       })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_UTOPIAN_REJECTED", payload: err })
      })
  }
}
```

Here is the reducer:

```
export default function reducer (state={
  utopianCash: [],
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  error: null,
}, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_UTOPIAN": {
      return {...state, fetching: true}
    }
    case "FETCH_UTOPIAN_REJECTED": {
      return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
    }
    case "FETCH_UTOPIAN_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        fetched: true,
        utopianCash: action.payload
      }
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

Combined reducers

```
// Combine Reducers in this file and export them
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import utopianReducer from './Utopian-reducer';

export default combineReducers({
  utopianReducer
})
```

The `response.data` in `"FETCH_UTOPIAN_FULFILLED"` returns undefined. And trying to use `this.props.data` or `this.props.data.utopianCash` in the Utopian component also returns undefined.

How do I successfully retrieve data from the API in the action and then use it in the component?

Comment: You don't `return` the reducer itself in `mapStateToProp`. You return the specific part of the store. Can you show us your reducer file?

Comment: Edited the post to include the reducer

Comment: @NickKinlen: Please include your `combineReducer` method

Comment: Edited again to show combine file

Comment: Maybe console log the `response` variable from the `getDiscussions` call and see what you get? Make sure it's the right shape and all that

Comment: debugging needs to start with getting a `response` from your api

Comment: Yep, look at your network tab in chrome and see what's the response of your request. Your object may not be inside response.data.

Comment: If I open the network tab I can see the data I am requesting and get a 200 status. If I try to console.log reponse.data inside my action after the .then (in the promise) it returns undefined.

Comment: Should `dispatch({ type: "FETCH_UTOPIAN_FULFILLED", payload: response.data })` be nested within the promise or is this a problem?

Comment: Here is the project. https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Nicknyr/Steem.js_API_Tutorial